# What does $_GET['iphone'] do?

Tags: php, mobile

I am working on a WordPress theme whose news stories are loaded in an iPhone app as well. We need the theme to detect whether the news story is being loaded from a mobile browser (chrome, safari, etc..) or from the iPhone app so we can serve a slightly different stylesheet.

Because I am mainly redesigning the existing theme, I know that the following code is responsible for completing that detection, but I can't seem to find out how/why it works:

```
if(isset($_GET['iphone'])) {
    //do different stuff
}
```

Can someone explain the $_GET['iphone'] part?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Basically it looks like the app simply appends `?iphone` to the url is it requesting.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information supplied to answer this. Please provide more code. Do you know what `$_GET` variables are? example.com/?iphone=something

Comment: Ohhh, that make sense now - thanks! see my comment on the accepted answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is for accessing variables in URL parameters, it's not related to any detection by itself, something must be adding it to URL.

In context of WordPress it might be related to `$is_iphone` global.

If you look at [`wp-includes/vars.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.8/src/wp-includes/vars.php) there is number of global variables like this, which WP fills up with data via user agent sniffing.

So `$is_iphone` is set there according to following logic:

```
if ( $is_safari && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'mobile') !== false )
    $is_iphone = true;
```

Comment: Oh gosh - of course it was something so simple. It looks like the app is simply appending `?iphone` to the end of the url when accessing it